# Weird issue with a php if statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I want to use this page to determine if the user has either updated a newsletter or created a new one. It connects to the database no problem and will update, but I can not get it to insert a fresh one as it gives me this error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

If I remove the if statement and just force it to insert a new record it will work with no issues.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "****";
$database = "test";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);

$title = $_POST["title"];
$body = $_POST["body"];
$transaction = "Record Added";

if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database, $con);

if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter (date, title, body)
    VALUES('1990-12-12', '$title', '$body')";       
}
else
{
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $transaction = "Record Updated";
    $sql = "UPDATE newsletter SET title='".$title."', body='".$body."' WHERE newsletterId =".$id;   
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo $transaction;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: If you remove **which** if statement?

Comment: Output the value of $sql inside the if () and show us

Comment: You have two unfiltered values `$title` and `$body` which are vulnerable to SQL injection, and also have the ability to break your query if they include `'`.

Comment: You probably mean `if (!isset($_POST["id"])) { ...`.

Comment: Your variables don't look like they're separated properly in the first SQL statement.

Comment: Got it working now. Fixed the logic issues etc, I'm frantically coding for a final and I'm fairly new to php so thank you for all the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic seems flawed, if an ID is posted you try to insert and when no ID is posted you try to update:

```
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $transaction = "Record Updated";
    $sql = "UPDATE newsletter SET title='".$title."', body='".$body."' WHERE newsletterId =".$id;        
}
else
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter (date, title, body)
    VALUES('1990-12-12', '$title', '$body')";   
}
```

That is where your error comes from, your `$id` is empty.

Apart from that you should look into sql injection. Switching to prepared statements is the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I didn't piece that together. SQL injection protection is the next thing I am working on, I am glad to hear I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes your query properly

```
$sql = "UPDATE newsletter SET title='".$title."', body='".$body."' WHERE newsletterId ='$id'";
```